# Display total number of records on gridview is inconsistent

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Sub Page_Load(...)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        BindData()
    End If
    gvCustomers.AllowPaging = False
    BindData()
    lblResult.Text = gvCustomers.Rows.Count.ToString & " records found "
    gvCustomers.AllowPaging = True
    BindData()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    ' Simple clean up text to return the Gridview to it's default state
    searchBox.Text = ""
    SearchString = ""
    BindData()
End Sub
```

Then this on gridview markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblResult" style ="font-weight:bold; " runat="server" 
     CssClass="style26"></asp:Label>
... another markup goes here ...
<asp:button ID="btnClear" Text="Reset" runat="server" />
```

What we would like to do is display total number of records on gridview on page load. 
This works fine as far as page load is concerned. When you search for a record, it displays the correct number of records found.

Now comes the problem part. If you  click on Reset button control, gridview should default back to total number of records. When you press the Reset button once, it doesn't reset to original total number.

You will have to press the Reset button twice before page reloads the total number of records on gridview.

Any ideas how to fix this so it reloads the first time Reset button is pressed?
Thanks alot in advance

```
Private Sub BindData()
    Dim strSearch As String

    'Protect against SQL Injection
    strSearch = Replace(searchBox.Text, "'", "''", 1, -1, 1)

    Dim query As String = "SELECT r.RoleId,l.LoginId, l.fullname,l.UserName,r.UserRoles FROM tblLogin l Inner Join tblRoles r on l.rights = r.roleId WHERE l.fullname LIKE '%" & strSearch & "%' "
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
    gvCustomers.DataSource = GetData(cmd)
    gvCustomers.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with postBack to me! Pls provide code for your reset button as well as your complete pageLoad eventHandler!

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz, thanks for your response.

That was all the code on pageLoad handler.

If you ade Sub PageLoad() Handles Me.Load
...the code I posted earlier.
</sub>

I posted the additional code you requested above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Re-Binding your dataSources again and again, I would suggest calling method `dataBind()`. So it becomes much clearer **that you first set number of records** within your gridView and **afterwards you re-bind it to show all your data**!

I assume this is a bit of event-order-problem here. Every button you click will return to the server and at first call your `PageLoad` eventHandler. Afterwards your `btnClear_Click` will get called.

So I hope I did get you right and suggest the following code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        BindData()
    End If
    ' gvCustomers.AllowPaging = True ' I would set this in markup!!
End Sub

Protected Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    ' Simple clean up text to return the Gridview to it's default state
    searchBox.Text = ""
    BindData()
End Sub
```

Rewritten answer as of given details! I assumed that `GetData(cmd)` returns a DataTable. In case I am wrong pls let me know.

```
Sub BindData()
    ' use SQL-Parameter instead - see below
    Dim query As String = "SELECT r.RoleId,l.LoginId, l.fullname,l.UserName,r.UserRoles FROM tblLogin l Inner Join tblRoles r on l.rights = r.roleId WHERE l.fullname LIKE '%@searchText%' "

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = searchBox.Text;

    Dim dt as DataTable
    dt = GetData(cmd)

    gvCustomers.DataSource = dt
    gvCustomers.DataBind()

    lblResult.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString & " records found "
End Sub
```

Within this code, your `BindData()` will be called once on page_load and afterwards only when you have to rebind your data (eg: *search, reset*)

Comment: `' insert gridview data-binding here`?

Comment: I assumed `BindData()` is a custom method  - or did you meant `Page.DataBind()`?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom method that contains the query.

I tried doing as you suggested but it would only give me total for that particular page as opposed to total for entire gridview.

Comment: For some reason, it is causing an error on my dataBound event on these lines:

`        ' Retrieve the DropDownList and Label controls from the row.
        Dim pageList As DropDownList = DirectCast(pagerRow.Cells(0).FindControl("PageDropDownList"), DropDownList)
        Dim pageLabel As Label = DirectCast(pagerRow.Cells(0).FindControl("CurrentPageLabel"), Label)`

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Still getting that same error on this line:

`Line 196:        Dim pageList As DropDownList = DirectCast(pagerRow.Cells(0).FindControl("PageDropDownList"), DropDownList)`

Comment: Did you debug your code? Check if `pagerRow` or `pagerRow.Cells(0)` or `pagerRow.Cells(0).FindControl("PageDropDownList")` is **null/nothing**!

Comment: If I don't use your code, I have no issues with that line of code.

All that code that is allow users to page through records by selecting page numbers from dropdownlist.

So, there is something in your code conflicting with it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I think you miss out some important piece of code. So you might edit your answer and provide more information/code/markup or just mail me relevant .aspx and .cs files to franz.pilgerstorfer@gmx.at

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38420/discussion-between-pilgerstorfer-franz-and-kenny)

Comment: Hi @PilgerstorferFranz,

I just emailed you a copy of the file to the address provided.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Why you can Use Container.DataItemIndex

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Slno" Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<div style="margin-top: 0px; color: Black;">
<asp:Label ID="txtslno" ForeColor="#000f9f" Font-Size="8" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="30px" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Very clear idea quite frankly.

If I can't give the users exactly what they are looking for, which is a total of all records, then I will accept your solution.

Thanks a lot for this.